# General Steps (guidelines, formulas and matices) in selecting wire-gauge for copper wires, when knowing the load characteristics?

Tags: wiring, load, copper

I would like to ask if someone could summarize the steps/process we follow in order to select an appropriate diameter of copper wiring for an application in which we just know the main characteristics for our load, like: the desired Amps we need for our load, the thermal conduction of our load in W/(m·K) and its resistance in Ω·cm. The wire will be soldered to the load which is made of Ti-alloy and it won't be very long (length is considered a known parameter, L in cm; same for our source, V_s in volts).

These steps may include formulas to calculate some factors/measures, or matrices from which we take specific values to consider for the final choice.

Since this is very general, because the process followed is what is asked, but as an example: let's say we need 3 Amps for our load, and that we know that the thermal conduction of our load is 6.7 W/(m·K) and its resistance is 17.8·10^(-5) Ω·cm.

Comment: How hot will the load become?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to consider three factors. Can the wire carry the voltage required without breaking down the insulation, can the wire carry the current you need "ampnicity" and how much voltage drop can you stand.

1. This is a factor of the quality and material of the insulation, the operating voltage and the environmental conditions. These numbers will come from the wire specification.
2. This is a factor of current, the cross sectional area of the wire the quality of the insulation (how well it puts up with heating) the environmental conditions particularly temperature and local heating effects e.g. multiple conductors packed into one loom. There are tables for this for specific applications.
3. The easiest, voltage drop is simply ohms per meter times meter times current. This usually drives the wire cross sectional area and makes 2. irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that one of the best places to start in a situation like this is to refer to existing tables regarding wire gauge and current capacity.  These readily available tables will show many needed details when looking to decide on the best wire gauge to be used.

Some of the details trickle down to negligible (like solder used) when only short wires are used but that assumes you are building in 'safety' margin.  If you are not building in a safety margin, then some of your details become a lot more important.

An example here:

[Wire Size Table](http://www.powerstream.com/Wire_Size.htm)